# Python: Using sub() tu replace string matched by regex

Tags: python, regex, replace

Given a xml document that is generated with too many blank spaces (i can't modify the file generator so i have to work with this file) that causes interpretation error i need to remove the blank spaces after every '>' symbol and before every '<' symbol.
I tried to do this using a python script and the function **sub(pattern, repl, string)**

As pattern i use two different regex as in the example below

```
line = re.sub(r"\s*<", "<", line)   #to remove every spaces after '>' symbol
line = re.sub(r">\s*", ">", line)  #to before every '<' symbol
```

The first one work as expected but the second one does not match anything although the regex is correct (checked with a regex checker).

Do you have any suggestion?

Here is a complete example:

```
import re
import os
f2 = open(r"C:\output_clean.xml", "a")

lines = open(r"C:\output.xml", "r").readlines()
for line in lines:
        line = re.sub(r"\s*<", "<", line)
        line = re.sub(r">\s*", ">", line)
        
        f2.write(line)

f2.close()
```

The actual file, **output.xml** is very long so I only reported a part of it (it is not important for the purposes of the example):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1>   <DOCVENTE>      <TIPDOC>         B1      </TIPDOC>      <RAGBOL>         A      </RAGBOL>      <ANNDOC>         2023      </ANNDOC>      <NUMDOC>         1072      </NUMDOC>      <DATDOC>         15/03/2023      </DATDOC>      <CLFR>         C      </CLFR>      <CODCLI>         002302      </CODCLI>      <CAMBIO>         0      </CAMBIO>      <RIFCAMBIO>         E      </RIFCAMBIO>      <SCOFIN1>         0      </SCOFIN1>      <SCOFIN2>         0      </SCOFIN2>      <SCONTO>         0      </SCONTO>      <PDCSCO>         210201      </PDCSCO>      <CODMAG>         01      </CODMAG>      <CAUMAG>         202      </CAUMAG>      <CODPAG>         B001      </CODPAG>      <CODVET>         025      </CODVET>      <CODPOR>         001      </CODPOR>      <CODTRA>         001      </CODTRA>      <ASPETTO>         Pallet      </ASPETTO>      <PESO>         150      </PESO>      <COLLI>         1      </COLLI>
```

Expected result (inside **output_clean.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1><DOCVENTE><TIPDOC>B1</TIPDOC><RAGBOL>A</RAGBOL><ANNDOC>2023</ANNDOC><NUMDOC>1072</NUMDOC><DATDOC>15/03/2023</DATDOC><CLFR>C</CLFR><CODCLI>002302</CODCLI><CAMBIO>0</CAMBIO><RIFCAMBIO>E</RIFCAMBIO><SCOFIN1>0</SCOFIN1><SCOFIN2>0</SCOFIN2><SCONTO>0</SCONTO><PDCSCO>210201</PDCSCO><CODMAG>01</CODMAG><CAUMAG>202</CAUMAG><CODPAG>B001</CODPAG><CODVET>025</CODVET><CODPOR>001</CODPOR><CODTRA>001</CODTRA><ASPETTO>Pallet</ASPETTO><PESO>150</PESO><COLLI>1</COLLI>
```

Actual result (inside **output_clean.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1><DOCVENTE><TIPDOC>         B1</TIPDOC><RAGBOL>         A</RAGBOL><ANNDOC>         2023</ANNDOC><NUMDOC>         1072</NUMDOC><DATDOC>         15/03/2023</DATDOC><CLFR>         C</CLFR><CODCLI>         002302</CODCLI><CAMBIO>         0</CAMBIO><RIFCAMBIO>         E</RIFCAMBIO><SCOFIN1>         0</SCOFIN1><SCOFIN2>         0</SCOFIN2><SCONTO>         0</SCONTO><PDCSCO>         210201</PDCSCO><CODMAG>         01</CODMAG><CAUMAG>         202</CAUMAG><CODPAG>         B001</CODPAG><CODVET>         025</CODVET><CODPOR>         001</CODPOR><CODTRA>         001</CODTRA><ASPETTO>         Pallet</ASPETTO><PESO>         150</PESO><COLLI>         1</COLLI>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you only want to have a clean XML and it's not a task you need to automate, I can recommend Notepad++ with the XMLTools plugin. I use its pretty-print feature multiple times daily.

Comment: Why do you have `*` after the `>`?

Comment: The way it looks, there's a lot of white space inside your XML elements. Instead of stripping the whitespace from before and after the tags, consider to parse the XML and `strip` the content of elements.

Comment: @MatBailie the * is a typo writing the post.  Corrected! Thank you

Comment: @white notepad++ was my first choice but the file is very big (about 100k lines) and notepad++ crash if i try to manipulate that file.

Comment: Without the typo, your code works.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your two conditions in a single pattern using lookarounds and replacing with an empty string:

```
import re
input_str = """<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1>   <DOCVENTE>      <TIPDOC>         B1      </TIPDOC>      <RAGBOL>         A      </RAGBOL>      <ANNDOC>         2023      </ANNDOC>      <NUMDOC>         1072      </NUMDOC>      <DATDOC>         15/03/2023      </DATDOC>      <CLFR>         C      </CLFR>      <CODCLI>         002302      </CODCLI>      <CAMBIO>         0      </CAMBIO>      <RIFCAMBIO>         E      </RIFCAMBIO>      <SCOFIN1>         0      </SCOFIN1>      <SCOFIN2>         0      </SCOFIN2>      <SCONTO>         0      </SCONTO>      <PDCSCO>         210201      </PDCSCO>      <CODMAG>         01      </CODMAG>      <CAUMAG>         202      </CAUMAG>      <CODPAG>         B001      </CODPAG>      <CODVET>         025      </CODVET>      <CODPOR>         001      </CODPOR>      <CODTRA>         001      </CODTRA>      <ASPETTO>         Pallet      </ASPETTO>      <PESO>         150      </PESO>      <COLLI>         1      </COLLI>"""
repl_pattern = re.compile(r"\s*(?=<)|(?<=>)\s*")
print(re.sub(repl_pattern, '', input_str))
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1><DOCVENTE><TIPDOC>B1</TIPDOC><RAGBOL>A</RAGBOL><ANNDOC>2023</ANNDOC><NUMDOC>1072</NUMDOC><DATDOC>15/03/2023</DATDOC><CLFR>C</CLFR><CODCLI>002302</CODCLI><CAMBIO>0</CAMBIO><RIFCAMBIO>E</RIFCAMBIO><SCOFIN1>0</SCOFIN1><SCOFIN2>0</SCOFIN2><SCONTO>0</SCONTO><PDCSCO>210201</PDCSCO><CODMAG>01</CODMAG><CAUMAG>202</CAUMAG><CODPAG>B001</CODPAG><CODVET>025</CODVET><CODPOR>001</CODPOR><CODTRA>001</CODTRA><ASPETTO>Pallet</ASPETTO><PESO>150</PESO><COLLI>1</COLLI>
```

Note: You should apply `sub` to the whole file string (`open(r"C:\output.xml", "r").read()`). Reading line by line, you will miss the preceding `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: It is generally *evil* and a menace to use regex to clean up XML content, which task should be delegated to a proper parser.  Given that you have no nested tags, you may try using the following replacement logic:

```py
inp = '<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1>   <DOCVENTE>      <TIPDOC>         B1      </TIPDOC>      <RAGBOL>         A      </RAGBOL>      <ANNDOC>         2023      </ANNDOC>      <NUMDOC>         1072      </NUMDOC>      <DATDOC>         15/03/2023      </DATDOC>      <CLFR>         C      </CLFR>      <CODCLI>         002302      </CODCLI>      <CAMBIO>         0      </CAMBIO>      <RIFCAMBIO>         E      </RIFCAMBIO>      <SCOFIN1>         0      </SCOFIN1>      <SCOFIN2>         0      </SCOFIN2>      <SCONTO>         0      </SCONTO>      <PDCSCO>         210201      </PDCSCO>      <CODMAG>         01      </CODMAG>      <CAUMAG>         202      </CAUMAG>      <CODPAG>         B001      </CODPAG>      <CODVET>         025      </CODVET>      <CODPOR>         001      </CODPOR>      <CODTRA>         001      </CODTRA>      <ASPETTO>         Pallet      </ASPETTO>      <PESO>         150      </PESO>      <COLLI>         1      </COLLI>'
output = re.sub(r'<.*?>|.*?(?=<.*?>|$)', lambda m: m.group().replace(' ', '') if not m.group().startswith('<') and not m.group().endswith('>') else m.group(), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1><DOCVENTE><TIPDOC>B1</TIPDOC><RAGBOL>A</RAGBOL><ANNDOC>2023</ANNDOC><NUMDOC>1072</NUMDOC><DATDOC>15/03/2023</DATDOC><CLFR>C</CLFR><CODCLI>002302</CODCLI><CAMBIO>0</CAMBIO><RIFCAMBIO>E</RIFCAMBIO><SCOFIN1>0</SCOFIN1><SCOFIN2>0</SCOFIN2><SCONTO>0</SCONTO><PDCSCO>210201</PDCSCO><CODMAG>01</CODMAG><CAUMAG>202</CAUMAG><CODPAG>B001</CODPAG><CODVET>025</CODVET><CODPOR>001</CODPOR><CODTRA>001</CODTRA><ASPETTO>Pallet</ASPETTO><PESO>150</PESO><COLLI>1</COLLI>
```

The regex pattern used here matches:

- `<.*?>` An XML tag
- `|` OR
- `.*?(?=<.*?>|$)` any intermediate content, up to, but not including,
  the next XML tag or the end of the string

We do a lambda replacement, which selectively strips spaces only from the intermediate content, but not from the tags themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/):

```py
from lxml import etree as ET

xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><ImportExportG1>   <DOCVENTE>      <TIPDOC>         B1      </TIPDOC>      <RAGBOL>         A      </RAGBOL>      <ANNDOC>         2023      </ANNDOC>      <NUMDOC>         1072      </NUMDOC>      <DATDOC>         15/03/2023      </DATDOC>      <CLFR>         C      </CLFR>      <CODCLI>         002302      </CODCLI>      <CAMBIO>         0      </CAMBIO>      <RIFCAMBIO>         E      </RIFCAMBIO>      <SCOFIN1>         0      </SCOFIN1>      <SCOFIN2>         0      </SCOFIN2>      <SCONTO>         0      </SCONTO>      <PDCSCO>         210201      </PDCSCO>      <CODMAG>         01      </CODMAG>      <CAUMAG>         202      </CAUMAG>      <CODPAG>         B001      </CODPAG>      <CODVET>         025      </CODVET>      <CODPOR>         001      </CODPOR>      <CODTRA>         001      </CODTRA>      <ASPETTO>         Pallet      </ASPETTO>      <PESO>         150      </PESO>      <COLLI>         1      </COLLI></DOCVENTE></ImportExportG1>'
dom = ET.fromstring(xml, ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))

for elem in dom.iter():
    if elem.text is not None: 
        elem.text = elem.text.strip()

print(ET.tostring(dom).decode())
```

With `XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)` you remove blank spaces between nodes, with `for` loop you remove blank spaces inside nodes.

`ET.fromstring` is for processing a string, if you need to process a file instead you can use:

```py
dom = ET.parse(xmlFilePath, ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))
```